# MYSQL outer join, doesn't return non-matching rows

Tags: mysql, outer-join

I have these two tables in my db

```
describe external_review_sources;
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ersID | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(50)  | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| logo  | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And

```
describe listing_external_review_source_rel;
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| lersrID | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| bid     | int(10)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| url     | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| ersID   | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| active  | int(10)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| order   | int(10)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I query these tables this way:

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM 
        listing_external_review_source_rel 
        RIGHT JOIN
        external_review_sources USING(ersID)
    where bid=902028 or bid IS NULL;

+-------+---------------+------+---------+--------+-------+--------+-------+
| ersID | name          | logo | lersrID | bid    | url   | active | order |
+-------+---------------+------+---------+--------+-------+--------+-------+
|     1 | G1            | a    |      17 | 902028 | url11 |      1 |     0 |
|     2 | D1            | b    |      18 | 902028 | url22 |      0 |     0 |
+-------+---------------+------+---------+--------+-------+--------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

As you can see results are showing up for bid=902028, how ever for a bid such as 866696 that does NOT exist in listing_external_review_source_rel, the results are empty

```
SELECT * 
FROM listing_external_review_source_rel 
     RIGHT JOIN external_review_sources USING(ersID) 
where bid=866696  or bid IS NULL;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

I expect the results to be this:

```
+-------+---------------+------+---------+--------+-------+--------+-------+
| ersID | name          | logo | lersrID | bid    | url   | active | order |
+-------+---------------+------+---------+--------+-------+--------+-------+
|     1 | G1            | NULL |     NULL| NULL   | NULL  |   NULL |  NULL |
|     2 | D1            | NULL |     NULL| NULL   | NULL  |   NULL |  NULL |
+-------+---------------+------+---------+--------+-------+--------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

That's what I have used the  "or bid IS NULL" condition.

What am I doing wrong and what query would give me this result? I basically am interested in having nonmatching rows in my results as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most people use LEFT JOIN so I'll rewrite it to be more standard:

```
SELECT *
FROM external_review_sources a LEFT JOIN
     listing_external_review_source_rel b ON a.ersID=b.ersID AND bid=866696;
```

Remember that an outter join returns all rows where the ON condition matches, and NULL where they don't.  In this case your match condition is more than just the ersID

Comment: Yes. The where conition must be moved to the ON clause otherwise its basically just an inner join.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM 
    external_review_sources e
    LEFT JOIN
    listing_external_review_source_rel r ON e.ersID = r.ersID AND r.bid = 866696
WHERE
    r.bid IS NULL;
```

When filtering on "outer tables", the filter needs to be a derived table or in the JOIN because you want to filter before the WHERE (logically). Also, a best practice is to use LEFT JOIN for clarity.

With a derived table

```
SELECT * FROM 
    external_review_sources e
    LEFT JOIN
    (
     SELECT * 
     FROM listing_external_review_source_rel
     WHERE bid = 866696
    ) r USING (ersID)
WHERE
    r.bid IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way, moving the test of the bid column out of the WHERE clause and into the JOIN:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM listing_external_review_source_rel ler
        RIGHT JOIN external_review_sources ers   
            ON ler.ersID = ers.ersID
                AND ler.bid=866696;
```